# Foreign key with multiple references

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, trigger, case, polymorphic-associations

I have the following three tables in mysql database named "THE_COLLEGE"

```
mysql> desc students;

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| STU_Id   | char(5)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| STU_Name | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> desc staff;

+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| STF_Id   | char(5)     | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| STF_Name | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> desc users;

+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Id         | char(5)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| user_Name  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Password   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

If a new row want to be inserted into the table "users", that row must be found in students table or staff table.

Which means a staff or a student can be a user.

Is it possible?

I tried with following foreign keys.

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT fky_stu
   FOREIGN KEY (ID)
   REFERENCES Students (STU_Id);

ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT fky_stf
   FOREIGN KEY (ID)
   REFERENCES Staff (STF_Id);
```

But the user table is allow to insert a row, if the row found in both tables (Student and Staff).

But I need to allow if the row found in any of the table (Student or Staff).

Comment: You need one more table (e.g. `persons`) and all the 3 tables' pks will be referencing it's pk.

Comment: Use the Party Model

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @ypercube is right.

You shall model an intermediary table to be able to enforce FKs:

[image]

A less formal model, in which FK enforcement would not be possible, could be:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want the USERS table to be the parent here, where STAFF and STUDENT are each types of users. Try flipping the fk relationships and doing the inserts in the other order.

Comment: nope. actually the user is an optional.
If a student like to use this system, he can register as a user.
If a staff like to to use this system, he also can register as a user.

But the user is not compulsory.

But a user must be exist on students table or staff table.
So the student table and the staff table are the parent tables of the user table.

Comment: I think that you can have the reference to USERS in STAFF and STUDENT but let it be null if they don't use it.